# Unable to find and change span text using jquery

Tags: jquery

My html and jquery code looks like below but for some reason I can change the text of the span. I m trying with both find and closest methods. Any ideas? thanks

```
<body>
<span class="classA">Text A</span>
<input id="testId" type="file" name="files" class="fileUp">
<span class="classA">Text B</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input.fileUp").change(function (event) {
            $(this).closest('span.classA').text('testing');
            $(this).find('span.classA').text('testing');

        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: use: $(this).parent().find('span.classA').text('testing');

Answer (score 1):

`span.classA` is not the closest element of `.fileUp`. Use `prev()` method like following.

```js
$("input.fileUp").change(function (event) {
    $(this).prev('span.classA').text('testing');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="classA">Text A</span>
<input id="testId" type="file" name="files" class="fileUp">
<span class="classA">Text B</span>
```